# Comparison Propositional Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Is a comparison a proposition?

"Life is like candy."

I believe it isn't, but I am not sure.

Comment: What is your definition of "proposition"?

Comment: A declarative statement that is either true or false, but not both.

Comment: A comparison might mean something more concrete, e.g. $1 \lt 2$, that we could agree is "either true or false, but not both".  The claim "Life is like candy" might more aptly be called a metaphor or an analogy.

Comment: Life is like a box of chocolates. We have this on good authority.

Answer (score 1):

Some people might agree with that statement, others might not.

So it is not a proposition, which must be a statement that is unambiguously and objectively either true or false.

Comment: Not everybody agrees that a proposition must be a statement that is unambiguously and objectively either true or false.

Comment: A weaker definition that may serve to accomplish the OP's request is that propositions (some say *sentences*) are capable of being only true or only false (in mathematics which depends on "the model"), so that an expression whose truth depends on something outside the model (e.g. on an observer's beliefs) is not a proposition in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, that is a proposition. Syntactically/grammatically it is a proposition in that it makes a relationship claim about two things. We can also combine it with other propositions, like 'If life is like candy, then death is like rotten teeth', and now we use propositional logic on it like any other propositions or combinations thereof.